# How does ::after and ::before work on properties other than content?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've always had a problem understanding the use of `::before` and `::after` on properties other than `content`. See for the code example below, there is this batch of code -

```
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after
{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

What does this mean in English? `border-radius` `before` and `after` what?
I thought commenting out the sections in the CSS will help me understand it by trial and error but it just got me more confused.

Can someone translate ONLY the `:before` and `:after` part in the below CSS in layman terms?

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after 
{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after 
{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dcecb;
  border-radius: 10.2em 0 0 10.2em;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
}
.loader 
{
  font-size: 11px;
  text-indent: -99999em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1em #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.loader:after 
{
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dcecb;
  border-radius: 0 10.2em 10.2em 0;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: 5.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body
{
   background: #0dcecb;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE11

Comment: @Royi Namir: The CSS is poorly written - the transform and animation CSS including the keyframes rules all have mismatched prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `content` property is declared in the second ruleset:

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after 
{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after 
{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
...
```

The reason `border-radius` is being specified separately here is because the author wants to apply it not only to the pseudo-elements, but also to the `.loader` element itself, as you can see from the selector.

All of the `::before` and `::after` rules matching the same `.loader` element cascade to create one of each pseudo-element for said `.loader` element. Since there *is* indeed a `content` property specified, the pseudo-elements *will* be rendered, and [all of the other properties applying to the pseudo-elements will take effect where applicable](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors):

> Pseudo-elements behave just like real elements in CSS with the exceptions described below and [elsewhere](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content).

In short, what you have is no different from your basic generated content CSS rule; the author has simply chosen to split some of the declarations into other rulesets for the purposes of selectors.

For what it's worth, here's what the CSS for each pseudo-element would look like had the author not chosen to split the `border-radius`, `position` and `content` declarations (and duplicated them once per pseudo-element instead):

```css
.loader:before
{
  border-radius: 50%;

  position: absolute;
  content: '';

  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dcecb;
  border-radius: 10.2em 0 0 10.2em;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
}

.loader:after 
{
  border-radius: 50%;

  position: absolute;
  content: '';

  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dcecb;
  border-radius: 0 10.2em 10.2em 0;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: 5.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
}
```

Comment: With unprefixed (and prefixed) versions, included for transform and animation ;)

Answer (score 3):

`.element::before`, and `.element::after` are [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-elements) that can represent an actual element if wanted, or insert content (or both).

You can imagine it working as follows:

```
<div>
<element BEFORE></element>
.. div content ..
<element AFTER></element>
</div>
```

Your example is a bad way to have to learn about these elements because it's pretty advanced usage.

Where `border-radius` is applied to these elements, it's just like you've applied to to any other element. If it has a width, size and some appearance (like a background colour), you'll see the border-radius applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

`:before` and `:after` is pseudo elements that is not in DOM (that means you can't click on them), but you can use them via css. `content` **is required** and usually set just to empty string. These elements can be used as normal div that *extends* bound of element. See example below

```css
.my-div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #454545;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  /* used to position :before and :after elements as they are absolute positioned */
}
.my-div:before {
  content: '<';
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.my-div:after {
  content: '>';
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='my-div'>CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

:before and :after is used to added something before of after the content. 
Specially if we want an icon of Mobile before "Call" we can use do it in 2 ways :

1 `<div><span class="ico"></span><span>Call</span></div>`
Now to .ico{ // we write css for background giving link of icon and its background size width height properties. }

2. Other way is by :before. `<div><span>Call</span></div>`

div span:before{ // this will have content:"" , than all background properties with position absolute and left top value.}
Thus with the help of before we don't have to write extra html tag. Same goes with :after tag

As your CSS is adding border to main text before an after , it will look messed up.
before and after needs proper content: "", it can be either blank or any value that we would like to appear before main text. like arrow , dot etc.

Hope this explanation helped.